# Cannot change UITableView back color in iPad UI

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview, backcolor

When I create UIViewController for iPhone I can easily change UITableView backcolor, but when I create for iPad I cannot change UITableView backcolor. Why?

I use XCode Version 4.2.

Comment: I mean UITableView Background attribute in inspector

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be different.

Did you try to change it in the code directly? In your controller implementation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [ self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor] ];

  [ super viewDidLoad ];

}
```

Without any code or more precision we can't really help you more than that, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But no changes. From interface builder and from code I cannot change this value.